# Netmiko - no output from device

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, netmiko

i've created a terminal application based on netmiko which is supposed to help users to automate their networking work. Script ask firstly to define devices, then define command and save method. Everything looks to work fine but with some devices and some commands (i did not found any corelation) there is no output. For example with cisco switch c3560 and 'sh run' command i can see only start of output:
`Building configuration...`
And there is no more onfiguration after.
Some blocks of code:

```
connection = ConnectHandler(**connection_profile)
for command in commands:
                    output = connection.send_command_timing(command)
                    commands_result+=f"{output}\n\n"
print(commands_result)
```

Should i use send_commands_timing method? Where can be the issue?

UPDATE
Use timing method with additional last_read parameter

```
output = connection.send_command_timing(command, last_read=8)
```

Comment: If you have found the answer to your problem yourself, please consider writing out a summary of how you solved the problem in your own answer, this will help anyone else who encounters the same issue you did and also make it clear that this question has been answered (it currently appears unanswered).

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding `global_delay_factor=4` the following to your ConnectHandler:

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from getpass import getpass

ip_addr = raw_input("Enter IP Address: ")

cisco = { 
    "device_type": "cisco_catalyst",
    'ip': ip_addr,
    "username": "barissonmez",
    "password": getpass(),
    "global_delay_factor": 4,
}

command = "show running-config"
net_connect = ConnectHandler(**cisco)
output = net_connect.send_command(command)
net_connect.disconnect()

print(f"\n{output}\n")
```